# Getting an invalid number error at random

Tags: oracle, ado.net, devart

I am using the following code with an Oracle ADO.Net provider (DevArt's [dotConnect Universal](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/universal/)). Funny thing is that it works sometimes and then most times it throws `Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException: ORA-01722: invalid number`

```
  string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  B.PRICE_TIER_KEY,b.label, a.INSERT_DATE   AS PriceEffectiveDate,B.PROGRAM_KEY AS PRICE_PROGRAM_KEY FROM GHX_MEMBER_TIER A INNER JOIN VHA_INT_PRICE_TIER B ON A.SRC_ID_VALUE = B.PRICE_TIER_KEY WHERE RowNum <=100";

        DbProviderFactory dpf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con_ORA_DevArt"].ProviderName);
        DbConnection conn = dpf.CreateConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con_ORA_DevArt"].ConnectionString;

        DbCommand dbcmd = dpf.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.Connection = conn;
        //dbcmd.Connection = uniConnection1;
        dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
        dbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dbcmd.CommandTimeout = 0;


        DataTable table = new DataTable();



        try
        {
            System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter da = dpf.CreateDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = dbcmd;
            // Fill the DataTable.

            da.Fill(table);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null && conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
            if (dbcmd != null)
            {
                dbcmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are the types of the relevant columns?  Are there any implicit conversions going on?

Comment: Yes. B.Price_Tier_Key is Number , and SOURCE_ID_VALUE is VARCHAR2( 255 Byte)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `ON A.SRC_ID_VALUE = B.PRICE_TIER_KEY` to `ON A.SRC_ID_VALUE = to_char(B.PRICE_TIER_KEY)`.

From [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i53062): "When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value.".  That implicit conversion is not always safe, you need to force Oracle to convert the number to a string instead.

Comment: Is that mean it will fail sometime and work fine randomly?

Comment: @InamurRahman Converting strings to numbers may randomly fail.  But numbers can *always* be converted to strings, and should always work.

Answer (score 5):

ORA-01722 is a data conversion error.  It happens when we attempt to turn a string into a number when the string contains a non-numeric value.  This can happen explicitly with a TO_NUMBER() cast or implicitly by using columns of different data types in a JOIN or a WHERE clause.

So you can now see that you've posted all the wrong information: what matters is the data structure and contents of the tables involved.  The most likely candidates for trouble are the two columns in the join: SRC_ID_VALUE and PRICE_TIER_KEY.  Are these both numeric columns or both strings?  If one is numeric and the other isn't, does the string one contain only numeric data?

This matters because Oracle will cast the string column to a number *before attempting the comparison*.

For instance, if table1 has this data ...

```
 1234
10789
```

... and table2 has this data ...

```
'1234'
'45o7'
```

the first rows will join fine but the second row will hurl ORA-01722 and derail the query.

The way around this is to convert the numeric column to a string using TO_CHAR().  This will prevent Oracle using any index on that column.  Which probably doesn't matter with your case, as you're mostly likely just doing full table scans on both tables, but it might matter with a more precise query.

---

> "I think that is a horrible feature in Oracle."

Casting a string to a number changes the sort order.  This ...

'1', '10', '2', '21', '3'

... becomes this ...

1, 2, 3, 10, 21

Of course it can't use the original index.

There is a workaround but it is somewhat involved.

1. Build a function to test an input string and which returns a number if it's numeric or null if it's not.
2. Build a function-based index using that function:

   create index src_id_num_fbi on GHX_MEMBER_TIER(is_a_number(SRC_ID_VALUE))    ;
3. Use that function in your query:

   ... ON is_a_number(A.SRC_ID_VALUE) = B.PRICE_TIER_KEY

Only you can decide whether this is worth the effort.

Comment: You are right. Its SRC_ID_VALUE and PRICE_TIER_KEY columns where first column is varchar2( 255) and second one is number. Thanks

Comment: Also, just noticed that useful tip of losing index use if we use to_char. I think that is a horrible feature in Oracle. I don't like Oracle. Sql Server 2008 R2 is way better than Oracle in this respect.

Comment: But WHY always the first time the original query works. Only the second time I run it it errors out. Then if I add a space to the query text, it again runs fine the first time.

Comment: Also, I noticed that all char values for SRC_ID_VALUE get converted to_number without any problems when I run this query: select to_number(A.SRC_ID_VALUE)  FROM  GHX_MEMBER_TIER A. So your explanation doesn't explain my issue.

Comment: My impression is still the same : ORACLE is not developer-friendly. Can ORACLE explain why my original Query runs fine the first time I run it?

Comment: My explanation was a best guess based on the scanty amount of useful information you posted.  There may be some other implicit data conversion in your code which I can't see.   Besides, your comment to @jonearles said his solution worked.  Well it worked because it addressed the issues in my explanation.

Comment: I've been using Oracle for over twenty years and I agree with you, Oracle doesn't care whether developers like it,  All it cares about is data integrity.   And performance.  And scalability.  And ruthless efficiency.

Comment: @APC- Yes, your explanation was also my answer, but I can only mark one person's answer as the answer. I hope I could mark multiple. Actually you offered more explanation but his response came earlier. I appreciate your help.

Comment: SO works like this: you should accept the best answer not the earliest post.  But I'm not trying to do Jon out of his rep ;)

Comment: @Sunil: When you ran `select to_number(A.SRC_ID_VALUE) FROM GHX_MEMBER_TIER A`, did you retreive all of the rows, or did your IDE only select a small number?  What makes these data conversion issues so frustrating is that they seem to magically go away.  But that's usually only because of bad luck.  When you use `ROWNUM <= 100` without any ordering, there's no telling which rows Oracle will choose.  Or if you have a bunch of joins and predicates, you normally can't control the order they are executed.

Comment: @jonearles: I retrieved all rows, so I did not have any rownum condition when I first saw this error.